# How to vertically align my <li> elements so that the text is in the middle ( vertically speaking ) of my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having 2 problems that I'm trying to solve here.

The first one is that I'm not completely sure how to vertically align my `<li>` elements so that the text is right in the middle ( vertically speaking ) of my navigation bar?

The second one is that for some reason, even though that I've set `.logo` to have `padding: 5px;` it doesn't work UNLESS I type !important after that.

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}
body {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.navigation {
    background-color: #171717;
}
.navigation-ul {
    display: flex;
}
.navigation-ul>li:not(.dropdown) {
    padding: 15px 13px 15px 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: #151719;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.logo img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 54px;
}
.logo {
  padding: 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class='navigation'>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="navigation-ul">
            <li class='logo'><img src='https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/red-background-ideal-for-christmas-picture-id152119339?k=6&m=152119339&s=612x612&w=0&h=Xxqd9B1xs5JymJYten1-cm2PESGtjen0evjxaCVOqoc='></li>
            <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Albums</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tags</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your vertical alignment of your navigation items set align-items: center; on your flex container like so:

```
.navigation-ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you'd need to do is this: In the `<ul>` inside your navbar, apply the following styling:

```
ul {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

This will make your `<ul>` centred vertically, and responsive as an added bonus!

Answer (score 0):

To center the navigation vertically: `navigation-ul {display: flex; align-items: center}`

Your logo padding has to have !important because it's overriding another style, `.navigation-ul>li:not(.dropdown)`, by the looks of it.
[image]

Comment: yes but .logo is below .navigation-ul>li:not(.dropdown) so shouldn't it override .navigation-ul>li:not(.dropdown) ?

Comment: That's my understanding of it, yes, but Chrome Dev-tools is telling me otherwise. I edited the answer with a screenshot ^